# Update LinqtoSql database with new schema changes?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have a Windows Phone 7 application that has been published to the marketplace. I'm using Sql CE with LinqToSql. When the app runs, it checks for the existence of a database from a connection string, and creates if it doesn't exist.

```
using (CheckbookDataContext db = new CheckbookDataContext(DBConnectionString))
{
    if (!db.DatabaseExists())
    {
        isNewLoad = true;
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

As I begin to plan new features, I foresee some changes to the database schema, whether it be adding a new column to an existing table, adding new tables, etc.

How does one go about updating the already existing database? Do I have to manually execute ALTER and CREATE table statements for my adjustments now that the database already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the local database migration overview for Window Phone.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394018(v=VS.92).aspx

And...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.data.linq.databaseschemaupdater(VS.95).aspx

Comment: This is great, Derek. Thanks for the links! Sometimes it is a matter of search terms. I never would have thought of 'migrating' the database.

Comment: I also just found this sample from MSDN. Published on the same day. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394022(v=vs.92).aspx. Full walkthrough with some different scenarios.